# play sound bytes with java

Tags: java, audio, openal

I want to write something like a music stream service with java. The db stuff and other logic is not the problem, but streaming something itself seems to be a challenge. My idea is the following:

After the client requests to stream one file, the server starts to send the bits of the requested music (wave) file to the client. Then i want construct a wave file on the client again with the bits from the server, and play it. BUT: streaming is, if you didnt download the whole file, but already can play the part you already downloaded. Lets say you downloaded 50 / 1000 bytes, i want to play them already. That would be streamung, wouldnt it? But how i can achieve this, using java, and maybe openal? I mean, i cannot write to a file; while usung it, can i?

Comment: Give it a try your self: create a `blob` field in your DB (with a sound file), `getBytes()` in `resultSet`  and play.

Comment: But then i always get the whole file at one, so if i have a bug music file for example 5mb, it downloads it and then plays it.. but that isnt streaming, is it?

Comment: play as soon as you get current byte

Comment: But how? How i can get "curremt byte" from the db and how i can play a "current byte" ?